# Issues creating a javafx project

Tags: netbeans, javafx

When ever i want to create a new `javafx` project in `netbeans`, when I get to the stage of naming my project, I get this error message:

> "Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab,enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website"

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what about you read the error message and follow the steps described in it?

Comment: Because the error message is unintelligible? Where is the "JavaFX tab"? Nowhere I can see.

Answer (score 4):

Just use NetBeans 8 (which has got rid of the confusing JavaFX Platform requirement).

From the [NetBeans 8 Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html):

> Unlike previous versions of NetBeans IDE, NetBeans IDE 8.0 does not require that you set up an "FX-enabled" Java platform in order to utilize JavaFX support in the IDE. You can develop JavaFX projects in the IDE if you install any standard Java platform that is JDK 7 Update 6 (or newer) or JDK 8.

On their Java download site, Oracle provide a [co-bundle of NetBeans 8 + Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) (Java 8 includes JavaFX 8).  I advise you just use the co-bundle.  Also grab a copy of [SceneBuilder 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) and you should be good to go with all of the tools you need for JavaFX development.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is still there all these years later (with no clearer error message), and I need the capabilities of at least Java 9. Recommending alternative products doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340742/7177756 will help you

```
"Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.Please go to Platform
 Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX 
 tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX 
 Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website"
```