# The specified folder does not contain a Java platform

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I am using Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319) and Java: 11.0.6; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1
System: Linux version 4.15.0-30-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_CA (nb)

If I try to creant a JavaFX project I get : Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340742/7096763) solve your issue?

Comment: Did not resolve the issue.    I use JDK 11 which includes javafx.