# Netbeans and Java FX - not running - assistance required please

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

Any clues, as to what i am doing wrong.  I want to run Javafx.  I have loaded `Java SE 13.0.1`, from the oracle website and also the latest version of `netbeans` (loaded last night from the website).

But when I go to build a javafx project on netbeans, in the "New Java Application" tab it has an error message

```
"failed to automatically set up JavaFX platform"  "please go to platform manager, create a non default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX runtime"
```

I would rather go back to basics and completely rebuild the Java and netbeans environment than try and create new links now but unclear what to do differently.

All help gratefully received - many thanks!!!

Comment: Start here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans

Comment: Have you checkd this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734994/issues-creating-a-javafx-project